# ERROR installing deepspeech in ubuntu server

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, installation, mozilla-deepspeech

I was actually trying to install deepspeech to a raspberry 4 whith pip3 and python 3.6.9 when I got this error :

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement deepspeech (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for deepspeech
```

when using

```
pip3 install deepspeech
```

Any idea? Thanks you very much.

Comment: I continue getting: ´´´ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement deepspeech (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for deepspeech´´´

Answer (score 3):

There are no whl files for deepspeech for rasberries on pypi, also no `tar.gz` source distribution. That is why it fails to find an installation candidate for you and gives you the error you are getting.

You will need to compile from source. You can find the instructions here:

https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/tree/master/native_client

Comment: Thanks you very much.